# AngularJS app doesn't display any views when I follow the Module Pattern Structure (without ngBoilerplate)

Tags: angularjs, ngboilerplate

Trying to improve the structure of my app directory, I installed [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) just to realize that I don't understand how to create an app from scratch using that framework, so I decided just to follow the module pattern *manually* (without ngBoilerplate).

Before migrate my app to the modular structure, I took these steps:

I created this directory.

```
src
|--app
|   |--home
|   |  |--home.js
|   |  |--home.html
|   |--about
|   |  |--about.js
|   |  |--about.html
|   |--app.js
|--assets
|--common
|  |--ui-router.js
|  |--ui-bootstrap.js
|--styles
|  |--stylesheet.css
|  |--bootstrap.css
|--index.html
```

I set up index.html

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<head>
<title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- AngularJS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="common/ui-router-0.2.10.min.js"></script>
<!--Bootstrap-UI-->
<script src="common/ui-bootstrap-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.11/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<!-- The App -->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/home/home.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The view -->
<div class="container" ui-view="main"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I set up the first view...

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="caption">
    Just setting up...
<br>
<buttom class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Hello</buttom>
</div>
</div>
```

..with its own module.

```
angular.module('app.home', [
'ui.router',
'firebase'
])
.config('config', ['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) { 
    $stateProvider // States configuration.
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    controller: "homeController",
                    templateUrl: "app/home/home.html"
                }
            },
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Home'
            }
    }); 
}])
.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$firebase', function($scope, $firebase) {}]);
```

And finally the app (basically a copy of the ngBoilerplate sample app).

```
angular.module('app', [
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'app.home'
])
.config('config', ['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) { // If you want "delay until everything is ready" use 'resolve' on states.
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
.run( function run () {
})
.controller( 'appCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location ) {
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
if ( angular.isDefined( toState.data.pageTitle ) ) {
  $scope.pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle;
}
});
});
```

When I open `index.html` in the browser, the page doesn't display the view *home* (the only view that I'm testing). And the console just says [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app.home&p1=undefined):

[image]

I've been stuck at this for awhile. What could be wrong?

Thanks in advanced!

**EDIT**

Here is [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WUyoytOxAutfSXBCuh95)

Comment: Can you please setup a plunker

Comment: Of course. I've already added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've been overthinking this one.

It is a simple error:
You have been passing the wrong arguments to `.config`.

```
// This is WRONG
.config('config', ['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

// This is RIGHT (no String as 1st argument)
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
```

See, also, this **[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tlwlXsF6Fh7gH8yCH5Dj?p=preview)**.

Comment: You're right, I'd been overthinking. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to use custom built modules:

1-by bootstrapping

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("MODULE-DIV-ID"), ['MODULE-NAME']);
```

2-Explicit definition on main Module, like:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'MODULE-NAME']);
```

which is more flexible in case you are using/loading your module inside 'view-main' for example while you are using angular $stateProvider